# Autoreply script not working using Dovecot + Sieve + Vacation on Debian 10

Tags: debian, email, dovecot, sieve

I am trying to configure the vacation sieve script on my Debian10 server, but it does not seem to work (it does not send an autoreply when receiving mail).

I didn't really understand how sieve treats the paths to the scripts, so I would really appreciate it if someone could explain them to me.

Could you please provide a step by step guide about how to configure an autoreply system on Dovecot, using sieve + vacation? The server is shared, is it possible to personalize the autoreply settings per user?

Here is what I have done until now:

Install Pigeonhole

```
sudo apt-get install dovecot-sieve dovecot-managesieved
```

In `/etc/dovecot/conf.d/15-lda.conf` activate sieve plugin

```
protocol lda {
mail_plugins = $mail_plugins sieve
}
```

In `/etc/dovecot/conf.d/20-lmtp.conf` activate sieve plugin

```
protocol lmtp {
mail_plugins = $mail_plugins sieve
}
```

In `/etc/dovecot/conf.d/20-managesieve.conf` uncomment

```
protocols = $protocols sieve
```

in `/etc/dovecot/90-sieve.conf` add under this line `sieve = file:~/sieve;active=~/.dovecot.sieve`

```
location = file:/etc/dovecot/vacation.sieve
```

I added the script below in the file `/etc/dovecot/vacation.sieve`

https://wiki2.dovecot.org/Pigeonhole/Sieve/Examples#Vacation_auto-reply

Restarted Dovecot

```
service dovecot restart
```

If you need any more info please feel free to ask.